# How get new screen position ( Three.js )

Tags: three.js

I using own post-processing effect ('black hole' ), how can I calculate new screen position and size Hole depending on moving camera?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include code if you're encountering a specific problem, or provide links to methods which have not worked for you so far.

Comment: I tried to multiply the hole position on the ModelViewProjection matrix.